# How to get a JSON representation of a Mongoose schema?

Tags: json, mongodb, mongoose, schema

I'm writing an API in Express, using Mongoose as my data layer. I'd like the API to be as self-describing as possible so my frontend can automatically generate forms and validation based on schema rules set up in my Mongoose models.

Is there any existing way to get a JSON representation of a Mongoose schema, or will I have to write my own? There seem to be plenty of JSON-to-Mongoose schema generators, but very little in the way of describing an existing schema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I probably don't get a point. You can define your schema as Object and then use `JSON.stringify` on it. Or if you want, you can access all schema paths through model as `Model.schema.paths`.